# UISearchbar scope is hidden behind the search text zone after adding constraint

Tags: objective-c, constraints, uisearchbar

I've come up against a problem I cannot sort out. I have a nib file where I added a table view and a UISearchbar with a scope bar. Everything was working perfectly until I added constraints to all the views (tableview, searchbar, a few labels and buttons). Since that moment, I cannot see the scope bar anymore. It seems to be hidden behind the searchbar because I can see a kind of blue surrounding the search area where text is entered (see below):

[image]
Does anyone have already been facing this problem?

**EDIT**:
This is the image with the constraints mentioned as a possible issue:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be either of below two constraint causing the issue.

1. Height constraint to the searchBar - you can resolve this by deleting the height constraint

[image]

OR

2. If your tableview has top constraint to the superview you will need to either delete it or you will not increase it till you see the scope bar.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. My tableview has a top constraint to the scope bar and not the superview, so it should probably be the first case scenario. But how can I delete the height constraint without having an error message stating "missing constraint" preventing me from running?

Comment: I have just added the image with the constraints in the Edit section if it can help

Comment: As I have worked, I din get missing constraint error. If you are getting it den you can increase the height constraint constant value to get this resolved.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But there is a problem, if I want to hide the scope bar when it is not editing, I will then end up with an extra space around my searchbar if the constraint is increased unless I changed my constraint programmatically everytime an editing is going on no?

Comment: yes, if you have height constraint then you can change the value programatically. In my case it adjusts automatically if you don't give the height constraint at all.

Comment: Okay thanks, but is it not dangerous not to have height constraints depending on the kind of device you are running your app?

Comment: Actually it doesn't, Auto layout adjusts the required height for the screen sizes. You need no worry about it. It's not only searchbar, you need not give height constraints for many controls in ui. This makes it easy to self resizing controls based on the content inside it.